# Android Studio: Programmatically Instantiating Horizontal Linear Layouts Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamic, android-linearlayout

**Finally found a workaround:** I decided to just use a table with a single row and then set stretchAllColumns to true. This means it just mimics a horizontal layout with spread-out views.

I am trying to instantiate a horizontal linear layout at runtime and I would like the elements in the layout to spread out along the full width of the layout. I would also like everything to be center-vertical aligned. This is currently what I've got:

```
LinearLayout tertiaryLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
tertiaryLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tertiaryLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
tertiaryLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
```

This instantiates the layout but the elements in it don't correctly fill the full width of it. I am also not sure how I can get them to be center-vertical aligned without changing setGravity to

```
tertiaryLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

This TextView is one of the five elements I add to the layout:

```
TextView dash = new TextView(getActivity());
dash.setText("-");
```

Two of the elements are ImageViews and the other three are TextViews. Here is how it looks currently:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGLyJ.jpg

EDIT:
The overall structure is a ScollView with a vertical LinearLayout. This LinearLayout holds lots of other vertical LinearLayouts, each with a horizontal LinearLayout. Hope that makes sense.
The parent view of `tertiaryLinearLayout` is here:

```
LinearLayout secondaryLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
secondaryLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
secondaryLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
...
secondaryLinearLayout.addView(tertiaryLinearLayout);
```

EDIT 2:
Here is my full code:

```
...
final LinearLayout linearLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.leagueLinearLayout);

List<Game> currentYearCategory = MainActivity.yearCategories.get(0);
for (int i = 0; i < currentYearCategory.size(); i++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(currentYearCategory.get(i).date);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
seekBarChange(linearLayout, root, 0);

// Set up seek bar
SeekBar yearSeekBar = root.findViewById(R.id.yearSeekBar);
yearSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        seekBarChange(linearLayout, root, progress);
    }

...
...

private void seekBarChange(LinearLayout linearLayout, View root, int progress){
    TextView yearTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.yearTextView);
    String newText = (1890 + progress * 10) + " - " + (1899 + progress * 10);
    yearTextView.setText(newText);

    final List<Game> currentYearCategory = MainActivity.yearCategories.get(progress);

    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentYearCategory.size(); i++) {
        // Create views
        LinearLayout secondaryLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        secondaryLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        secondaryLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        View separatorView = new View(getActivity());
        separatorView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));

        TextView date = new TextView(getActivity());
        date.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        date.setText(currentYearCategory.get(i).date);

        LinearLayout tertiaryLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        tertiaryLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tertiaryLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        tertiaryLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        ImageView homeImage = new ImageView(getActivity());
        homeImage.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        if (currentYearCategory.get(i).celticIsHome){
            homeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celtic_logo);
        } else {
            homeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rangers_logo);
        }

        TextView homeScore = new TextView(getActivity());
        homeScore.setText(currentYearCategory.get(i).fullTimeScore.substring(0, 1));

        TextView dash = new TextView(getActivity());
        dash.setText("-");

        TextView awayScore = new TextView(getActivity());
        awayScore.setText(currentYearCategory.get(i).fullTimeScore.substring(2));

        ImageView awayImage = new ImageView(getActivity());
        awayImage.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        if (currentYearCategory.get(i).celticIsHome){
            awayImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rangers_logo);
        } else {
            awayImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celtic_logo);
        }

        // Add views
        tertiaryLinearLayout.addView(homeImage);
        tertiaryLinearLayout.addView(homeScore);
        tertiaryLinearLayout.addView(dash);
        tertiaryLinearLayout.addView(awayScore);
        tertiaryLinearLayout.addView(awayImage);

        secondaryLinearLayout.addView(separatorView);
        secondaryLinearLayout.addView(date);
        secondaryLinearLayout.addView(tertiaryLinearLayout);

        final int gameNum = i;
        secondaryLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGameActivity(currentYearCategory, gameNum);
            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(secondaryLinearLayout);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems `tertiaryLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);` is enough. You won't need `tertiaryLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `PARENT` view that the `tertiaryLinearLayout` will be added to is `wrap_content` for the `layout_width`. Try to make its width `match_parent`. You should have a look on [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/2S2ZyqLVn10) at 2:52s

Comment: Cool thanks for the quick response! I'll have a look at it tonight.

Comment: Unfortunately, the parent view of `tertiaryLinearLayout` is set to `MATCH_PARENT` (see edit).

Comment: I means that the `PARENT`s must be `match_parent`. So all `ViewGroup`s that contain the `tertiaryLinearLayout` and its parent must be `match_parent`. To be simple I suggest that you should set the background with different color to these views and see them are `match_parent` or not

Comment: All parents of `tertiaryLinearLayout` are set to `MATCH_PARENT` too. I tried setting the background colour of `tertiaryLinearLayout` and it does take up the full width of its parent, the children of it just don't spread out across its width.